# Navigating to second string text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

Here is the lxml, it's saved as sample.html.

```
<html> 
    <body> 
    <div class ="ecopyramid"> 
        <ul id ="producers"> 
            <li class ="producerlist"> 
                <div class ="name">A1</div> 
                <div class ="number">100000</div> 
            </li> 
            <li class ="producerlist"> 
                <div class ="name">B1</div> 
                <div class ="number">100000</div> 
            </li> 
        </ul> 
        <ul id ="primaryconsumers"> 
            <li class ="primaryconsumerlist"> 
                <div class ="name">A2</div> 
                <div class ="number">1000</div> 
            </li> 
            <li class ="primaryconsumerlist"> 
                <div class ="name">B2</div> 
                <div class ="number">2000</div> 
            </li> 
        </ul> 
        <ul id ="secondaryconsumers"> 
            <li class ="secondaryconsumerlist"> 
                <div class ="name">A3</div> 
                <div class ="number">100</div> 
            </li>

            <li class ="secondaryconsumerlist"> 
                <div class ="name">B3</div> 
                <div class ="number">98</div>
            </li> 
        </ul> 
        <ul id ="tertiaryconsumers"> 
            <li class ="tertiaryconsumerlist"> 
                <div class ="name">A4</div> 
                <div class ="number">80</div> 
            </li> 
            <li class ="tertiaryconsumerlist"> 
                <div class ="name">B4</div> 
                <div class ="number">50</div> 
            </li> 
        </ul> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Here is the code to navigate through the sample.html above:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("sample.html", "r") as sample_pyramid:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(sample_pyramid, "lxml")

soup_object = soup.find("ul", id="secondaryconsumers")
print soup_object.li.div.string
```

So in this code I am able to first specify the parent location of the text "A3" first by the tag "ul" and id "secondaryconsumers", then in the print command I specify further by the ".li.div.string" suffix and output the desired text of "A3". My questions are as follows:

1) How do I code in order to call/print the text "B3" in this example?

2) How do I code in order to call/print the text "98" (below "B3") in this example?

I have tried many things with no success, I am able to call the first text object through the navigation, but not the second text object within the shared tags.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to get names and numbers:

```
names = soup.select('ul#secondaryconsumers > li.secondaryconsumerlist > div.name')
numbers = soup.select('ul#secondaryconsumers > li.secondaryconsumerlist > div.number')

print [name.text for name in names]
print [number.text for number in numbers]
```

Prints:

```
[u'A3', u'B3']
[u'100', u'98']
```

---

Example code for the follow-up question in comments:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<div class="span9">
    <table class="result-data table" border="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="result-item highlighting">
            <td class="result-category" scope="row">Name:</td>
            <td class="result-value-bold" colspan="4" itemprop="item">
                Robin Hood
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find('td', class_="result-value-bold").get_text(strip=True)
```

prints `Robin Hood`.

Or, alternatively first find parent `table` and `tr`:

```
table = soup.find('table', class_='result-data')
tr = table.find('tr', class_='result-item')
print tr.find('td', class_="result-value-bold").get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Alecxe, a follow-up question, in your print command, it used a for loop, is it possible to just print, say, the second one, so it only print out "98"?

Comment: @KubiK888 sure, you want to get just `98` from the above html, right? Is it always inside the second `li` with class `secondaryconsumerlist` ? Thanks.

Comment: Two part questions: 1) Yes it is always inside the second "li" with class "secondaryconsumerlist", how can I print/return just that value and not all? 2) I have tried to apply the CSS selector method in the real site, but it turned out there are spaces and hyphens in the class or id attributes, for example <li class="second consumer-list">, is there a way to modify the CSS selector in BeautifulSoup, I tried to read through the documentation link you mentioned but couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: @KubiK888 it is definitely solveable. Just to be clear, can you provide the html from the real site? just the `<div class ="ecopyramid">...</div>` part.

Comment: <div class="span9">
  <table class="result-data table" border="0">
   <tbody>
    <tr class="result-item highlighting">
     <td class="result-category" scope="row">Name:</td>
     <td class="result-value-bold" colspan="4" itemprop="item"> Robin Hood </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to make it looks hierarchical in comment, but each is a "child" of the previous tag, except the two <td> tags are siblings.

Comment: @KubiK888 you can edit the question and include it there. Sorry for bothering - just want to know the exact structure of the page so that I can provide you with the solution. Thanks.

Comment: The comment makes the spacing and tabbing structure disappear. In my two comments before, <td> are sibling tags, they are child of <tr>, which is a child of <tbody>, which is a child of <table>, which is a child of <div>. Let me know if that's clear. Basically I want to know how to deal with class attribute with space and hyphens within "  ", I would like to get the "Robin Hood" as an output and not "Name:"

Comment: @KubiK888 I've updated the answer and included the sample code. Does it help?

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks Alecxe. I never knew you can call the attribute of the desired text directly, I thought you had to call the parent first (which you proved to be unnecessary). I wonder what if say ('td', class_="result-value-bold") is used elsewhere and the only way to identify this one is calling the parent <tr class="result-item highlighting">, is there a good, universal way to take care this situation?

Comment: @KubiK888 you can first find the parents, see the update in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much Alexce, I got it and had a much better grasp on how to use BeautifulSoup now.

Comment: @KubiK888 glad to help, consider accepting the answer, thank you. Also, see if any of the questions you asked before have unaccepted answers and there are answers that deserve it.

Comment: One last follow-up question if you don't mind, what if the tag and attributes for "Name:" and "Robin Hood" are exactly the same, for example let's change the tag for "Name:" to be <td class="result-value-bold" colspan="4" itemprop="item">, how can I always just extract the second instance?

Comment: I have tried this using the next_sibling but it return some empty value: #label = soup.find("td", class_="result-value-bold")
#sibling = label.next_sibling
#print sibling

Comment: @KubiK888 try using `find_all()` and getting the second (`[1]`) element.