# How to get text from this cede using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to get this text 'Please login again' using bs4

```
<div id="msgDiv" align="left" class="msgdiv">
<font class="errorfont">
    <xmp style="white-space: normal;margin:0px;font-family:tahoma,arial,san-serif;">Please login again.</xmp>
</font>
```

I have tried this but didn't get anything:

```
page.select('#msgDiv > font > xmp')
```

Comment: Please check the following example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923826/navigating-to-second-string-text-using-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this would help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<div id="msgDiv" align="left" class="msgdiv">
<font class="errorfont">
    <xmp style="white-space: normal;margin:0px;font-family:tahoma,arial,san-serif;">Please login again.</xmp>
</font>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.select('div#msgDiv > font.errorfont > xmp')[0]
print(tag.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

It's works fine with following code
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
text = """
     <div id="msgDiv" align="left" class="msgdiv">
        <font class="errorfont">
           <xmp style="white-space: normal;margin:0px;font-family:tahoma,arial,san-serif;">Please login again.</xmp>
        </font>
    </div>
      """

   soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
   print(soup.xmp.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<div id="msgDiv" align="left" class="msgdiv">
<font class="errorfont">
    <xmp style="white-space: normal;margin:0px;font-family:tahoma,arial,san-serif;">Please login again.</xmp>
</font>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'msgdiv'}):
    for xmp in tag.find_all('font'):
        print(xmp.text)
```